# Creating an Array of JS objects from Firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling with creating an array of object from firebase database.
I need to get an array like this:
[see the console printscreen of an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcMoj.png)

Instead Iam getting this: [see the console printscreen of an array Iam getting when retrieving date from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ9mq.png)

Here is the code Iam using to get the data:

```
function gotData(data) {
  //console.log(data.val());
  var mesta = data.val();
  var keys = Object.keys(mesta);
  //console.log(keys);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    var nazevmesta = mesta[k].nazevmesta;
    var lat = mesta[k].lat;
    var lng = mesta[k].lng;
    var mesto = new Object();
    mesto.name = nazevmesta;
    mesto.lat = lat;
    mesto.lng = lng;

    var mestaz = new Array();
    mestaz.push(mesto);
    console.log(mestaz);


  }
}
```

I am trying to create the array at the very end.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `mestaz` array only once outside the loop not a new instance every iteration of the loop

```
var mestaz = []; /// create one array

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  var k = keys[i];

  var mesto = {
    name: mesta[k].nazevmesta,
    lat: mesta[k].lat,
    lng: mesta[k].lng
  };

  // push each object to same array
  mestaz.push(mesto);

}

// log whole array after adding all of the elements in the loop
console.log(mestaz);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks alot!